# Ensure program is running with Windows 7 Task Scheduler

Tags: python, windows, windows-7, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have set up a python script to run daily from my pc by adding it to the start up section in Windows 7.

However, does any know how I can set up a job (probably from Task Scheduler) to alert me if the program has stopped running i.e. if for some reason the cmd screen is closed etc... so that I can restart it or automatically restart it

Mike

Comment: The problem with using a windows services is that I am doing this without Admin rights on my PC so I can't follow that approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it sounds like what you actually are looking for is windows services.

## About services

If you don't know what a windows service is, then msdn have some [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  about it.

## Creating a windows service in python

For a concrete example on how to do this in python, go [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576451-how-to-create-a-windows-service-in-python/)